# How to save a chart as an image in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a chart in QT. Is there a way that I can save this as an Image?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say chart, I assume it is some kind of vector graphics or similar. I usually export them as PDF using QPrinter and then use them in my documents (LaTeX, Keynote, ...).
Here is a code snippet which might help. Untested, since I ported it in my head from Python back to C++:

```
  QPrinter *printer = new QPrinter();
  printer->setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
  QPrintDialog *dialog = new QPrintDialog(printer);
  dialog->setWindowTitle("Print Plots");
  if (dialog.exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
     return;
  QPainter *painter = new QPainter();
  painter->begin(printer);
  ui->someQwtPlot->print(painter, printer->pageRect());
  painter->end();
  delete(dialog);
  delete(painter);
  delete(printer);
```

I am assuming here you are creating a plot with QwtPlot, but any QWidget or object supporting rendering to a QPainter will do. See [QWidget::render()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#render-2) for details. The code above actually allows you even to print to a real printer. But I usually just set "Print to PDF" in the printer dialog. If you do not need the printer dialog, you can skip it and use [QPrinter::setOutputFilename](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprinter.html#setOutputFileName) to set the PDF filename directly.